# Multi Currency Store

Tags: multicurrency, geoip

in setting up a store with multiple currencies is it best to only offer option at checkout or based on entry IP address?

Comment: you can setup multiple currency switcher option near logout button its the default functionality already present in magento 2 you need to make any changes or customization unless if you have some other which i don't see from this question.